# What does it mean when I select to 'clear data'?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread

If I look at the options to manage an application and select to clear data, what data is specifically being cleared? Is there a way to find out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the data stored by the app in the folder /data/data/app_name/ will be cleared. You cant specify which data to clear. The app would be like when it was installed or updated.

Comment: What data is stored in the data/data/app_name directory?

Comment: usually settings and other app data. For example in a browser data such as history, saved passwords, cache, preferences, etc.

Comment: Is there an easy way to access the data or do I need to install developer tools? Also is the data encrypted or stored in plain text?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: You need root to read the data. Whether or not it's in plaintext is entirely up to the app developer, just like with any other piece of software.